# redirect user to same page but to a specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to redirect the user to the same page but show the tab "#myRegistrations" as active when the user click in the "#myRegistrationsClean".

But with the code below the user is redirected to the same page but the #myRegistrations tab dont stay active. This is beacuse the code below just refreshes the page like "window.location.reload();".

Do you know how to redirect to the same page but with the "#myRegistrations" active? The url that turns the "myRegistrations" tab to active is "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=2#myRegistrations".

```
$('#myRegistrationsClean').click(function() {
    alert("test");
    @if(session('searchedConferences'))
        // $('#cleanSearch').click(); dont works
        window.location.reload();
    @endif
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `window.location.hash`

```js
$('#myRegistrationsClean').click(function() {
    alert("test");
    if(session('searchedConferences')) {
        // $('#cleanSearch').click(); dont works
        window.location.hash = "myRegistrationsClean";
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
.modal-overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<a href="#login-modal">Sign In</a>

<div id="login-modal" class="modal-overlay" onclick="(function(e){if(e.path.length<=5)window.location.hash=''})(event)">
  Modal Content
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This below code will work as per your need. "scrollTop" function used to scroll through the window. Make sure you are using **jQuery library** because animate function is dependent on it.

`jQuery('body, html').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#myRegistrations").offset().top});`